# CodeFirst. I have manually deleted the DB files

Tags: code-first

I created and ran codefirst application. It created DB in files in Users/UserName
folder and added data into it. I could even pull it out. Then I manually deleted these files. I expected that if I
delete files than entity framework would create a new ones. But it throw
exception with the message: {"Cannot open database \"CodeFirstTest.Program+CarRegisterContext\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'NAZAR\Nazar'."}
I didn't change nothing in properties. There isn't connection string even. All are default that entity framework nuget set.

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to start all over again!

Answer (score 0):

After restarting VS I found the server where the database was created. Before restarting it wasn't appeared in SQL Server Object Explorer. Then I deleted the database fron it and now all works fine.